# Find the maximum value of $ f(x) = \int^{x}_{0} \sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^4}~dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the maximum value of $f(x)$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $$ f(x) = \int^{x}_{0} \sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^4}~dy$$

I'm guessing that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus can't be used because the integrand is a function of $x$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See liebniz integral rule

Comment: Mathematica Can solve this integral!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: so?

Comment: You may enforce the substitution $y=x\cdot t$ then prove that $f(x)$ is increasing, showing that the maximum is achieved at the right endpoint, where $f(x)=f(1)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479035/find-the-maximum-of-fx-int-0x-sqrtx2-x2y4-dy-x-in0-1 (found by approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x)%20%3D%5Cint_0%5Ex%5Csqrt%7B(x%5E2-x)%5E2%2By%5E4%7D%5C%2C%20dy%24&p=1)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio could you please elaborate on how you do this substitution? And why are we allowed to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Letting $y=x t$ (such that $dy=x\,dt$) we have
$$ f(x) = x^3 \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\left(1-\tfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+ t^4}\,dt $$
so $f(x)$ is increasing as the product between two non-negative and increasing functions. For any $t\in(0,1)$, $0<x_1<x_2<1$ leads to
$$ 1-\frac{1}{x_2}>1-\frac{1}{x_1},\qquad \left(1-\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^2+t^4 > \left(1-\frac{1}{x_1}\right)^2+t^4 $$
hence by integrating the last inequality for $t\in(0,1)$ we get
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\left(1-\tfrac{1}{x_2}\right)^2+ t^4}\,dt > \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\left(1-\tfrac{1}{x_1}\right)^2+ t^4}\,dt $$
and the maximum of $f(x)$ is attained at $x=1$:
$$ f(1) = \int_{0}^{1}t^2\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.$$