# Find the maximum of $f(x) =\int_0^x\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^4}\, dy, x\in[0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Find the maximum of $$f(x) =\int_0^x\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^4}\, dy, x\in[0,1].$$

I am generally familiar with the process of how to find the maximum of a function on a given interval, however I really don't even know where to start with this one, any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: I don't really know where to start to find this derivative.

Comment: If $f(x)=\int_0^xg(x,y) dy$, then $\displaystyle f'(x)=g(x,x)+\int_0^x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)dy$

Comment: Since the integrand is always greater than 0, i.e. for all $x, \sqrt{(x^2 - x)^2 + y^4} > 0$.  What does that say about this integral?  Could $f(x)$ ever be decreasing?  Where is the min and where is the max?

Comment: @DougM $g(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^{20}}\,\mathrm{d}y$ decreases somewhere on $[0,1]$. The problem is that the integrand is a function of $x$, so you're integrating a different function for each $x$. You're not just accumulating more area as $x$ increases.

Comment: @Math101 Thank you for the help. May I ask where does this come from? I don't think I've seen it before. Also I have found ∂(,)/∂, however I don't know how I can manually compute the antiderivative?

Comment: @Shane Hogan It is just a direct computation: $$ f(x+h)-f(x) = \int_0^{x+h}g(x+h,y)dy -\int_0^x g(x,y)dy = \left(\int_0^{x+h}g(x+h,y)dy -\int_0^xg(x+h,y)dy\right)+\left(\int_0^xg(x+h,y)dy-\int_0^x(g(x,y)dy\right).$$

Divide all by $h$ and let $h\rightarrow 0$, the first parentheses become $g(x,x)$ and the second $\displaystyle \int_0^x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dy$ .

Comment: @Math101: exchanging limits is not a "direct computation".

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 12.0 answers

```
Maximize[{Integrate[Sqrt[(x^2 - x)^2 + y^4], {y, 0, x}],  x >= 0 && x <= 1}, x]
```

$$\left\{\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)},\{x\to 1\}\right\} $$

Comment: The first solution boils down to $x=1/3$.

Comment: I don't know what Mathematica is doing, but it looks like the answer is wrong? Unless I'm making a mistake, the number in the answer is $0.328125$, while $f(1)=\tfrac13$.

Answer (score -2):

First, we have to get the derivarive of $ f $.

So, let’s use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in order to find it:

$$f’(x) = \sqrt{(x^2 - x)^2 + x^4} \cdot 1
= |x| \sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$$

Since the interval is positive, it’s just $x $ times that square root.

Therefore, we must avaluate at $f’=0$ or where the function “does not exist”. However, the function is well behaved at the whole real line, since the roots are complex conjugates.
$$f’(x) = x \sqrt{2x^2 -2x +1} = 0.$$
Therefore, $ x = 0, f(0)=0$.

Now, do not forget the boundaries of the interval: 0, 1. Since, we have already gotten the result above:

$f(1) =$ something that I will finish further, I’m kinda busy right now. But that’s the idea.

Comment: @MrN: The expression you wrote is not the derivative of $f$. The fundamental theorem of calculus gives $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x F(t)~dt = F(x)$, but this only applies when the function inside the integral does not depend on $x$; but in this case, it does depend on $x$. See Math101's comment on the question for how to compute $f'$.

Comment: Oh shit. Pardon me guys, I did not know that. Thanks for correcting me Clive!